# change img src according to folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a main folder "main". It has a page inside with name "test1.html". It also has the images folder.
The image folder has the image "pic1.png".

There is also a sub folder in the "main" folder called "sub" which has a page "test2.html".

**SCENARIO**: I am inserting pic1.png in img tag via jquery in both the pages (in the root folder as well as the sub folder). How should I handle the src for different pages? i.e,

test1.html -- images/pic1.png

test2.html -- ../images/pic1.png

Comment: what do u mean by "handle the src for different pages".. confused

Comment: obv. it means the src attribute of the image should change according to the location of the page, i.e the page is in the root folder or any of the sub folders.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you include the relative path from the web root for both sources.

```
/images/pic1.png
```

Here is a good [site](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/) for an explanation of relative path.

Comment: thnx but i tried this and its not working.

Comment: What is the url to the image?

Comment: see, If the page is in the sub folder the image src should be "../images/pic1.png". If the page is in the root folder itself, the image src should be "images/pic1.png"

Comment: I understand, but in order for this to work you need the path from the root of your site. This means the part that comes after your domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You can check location with regex and apply src using attr function in jQuery

```
(''+window.location).match(/http:\/\/[^\/]*\/*root\/?(.*)/)[1]
```

this will match everything in url after root without first slash.

if it's in root directory it will be empty and you can apply `..` in how many slashes out in that variable

```
var path = (''+window.location).match(/http:\/\/[^\/]*\/*root\/?(.*)/)[1]
if (path) {

   var prefix = '';
   for (var i=path.match(/\//).length;i--;) {
       prefix += '../';
   }
   $('img').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this)
      $this.attr('src', prefix + $this.attr('src'));
   });
}
```

this will change all src attributes of images on the page